# Force Private browsing

Tags: tabbed-browsing, private-browsing

Is there a way to force private browsing in Safari 5 on a Mac?

Comment: As a web site, as administrator for other users, or what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it works in Safari 4.

A script is needed,

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
    tell menu bar 1
    tell menu bar item "Safari"
    tell menu "Safari"
    click menu item "Private Browsing"
    end tell
    end tell
    end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

you can follow this link for more information:
http://www.macworld.com/article/139714/2009/03/enableprivatebrowsing.html